# Understanding fixef() output of fixed effects coefficients

Tags: r, mixed-model, panel-data, intercept, plm

I have a panel data set with several `ID`'s and each has a certain number of `year` observations.
When I fit a fixed effects regression and obtain the fixed effects coefficients, I get the following:

```
# Fixed Effects Model using plm
fixed_model <- plm(score1 ~ score2, data, model= "within", index = c("ID", "year"))

# Obtaining fixed effects coefficients
fixef(fixed_model)

# Output
# The first row are the ID's from 1-35
     1      2      4      6      7      8     10     11     12     17     18     21     22     25     26     30     32     34     35 
72.478 73.209 70.275 74.038 71.113 72.565 71.586 72.595 72.218 68.546 70.057 77.670 75.949 65.051 78.645 65.837 72.483 69.686 68.381
```

I'm struggling to understand the meaning of these coefficients. Do they represent the **intercept** of each of the trends for these `ID`'s? i.e. do they represent the `score1` they achieved in `year1`?

Another possible interpretation is that *for patient `ID=1`, the mean response (i.e. `score1`) is 72.478*?

Answer (score 0):

These are not coefficients but the individual intercepts (in the one-way case, corresponding to the selected effect (individual or time fixed effect)). I suggest you make yourself a little more acquainted with the theory of fixed effect models. Any good econometrics textbook will cover this.

The man page of the command should make it clear as well and has references to the literature, so I suggest you read `?plm::fixef`, esp. the examples section (and there esp. how to calculate the fitted values via the fixed effects):

```
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
gi <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, model = "within", effect = "individual")

# calc. fitted values of oneway within model:
fixefs <- fixef(gi)[index(gi, which = "id")]
fitted_by_hand <- fixefs + gi$coefficients["value"]   * gi$model$value +
                           gi$coefficients["capital"] * gi$model$capital
yhat <- as.numeric(gi$model[ , 1] - gi$residuals) # fitted values
all.equal(as.numeric(fitted_by_hand), yhat) # TRUE
```

Take heed, the two-way unbalanced case is calculated a little differently (refer to the man page of `fixef` and/or this answer on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/33673756/4640346).